# Router Navigation SlideIn Animation not working

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-animations

I am trying to implement slideIn animation while the router navigates. I have read some documentation and implemented the code in sample application. I don't see any errors, but the animation is not working. Please guide me where I am missing.

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent,data: {animation: 'HomePage'} },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, data: {animation: 'AboutPage'} }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { slideInAnimation } from './animation';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [slideInAnimation] // register the animation
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'animationtest';
  prepareRoute(outlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="">home</a>
    <a routerLink="about">about</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
  <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>   
</main>
```

**animation.ts**

```js
import {
  trigger,
  animate,
  transition,
  style,
  query,
  group,
  animateChild
} from '@angular/animations';


export const slideInAnimation =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('HomePage <=> AboutPage', [
      style({ position: 'relative' }),
      query(':enter, :leave', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%'
        })
      ]),
      query(':enter', [
        style({ left: '-100%'})
      ]),
      query(':leave', animateChild()),
      group([
        query(':leave', [
          animate('300ms ease-out', style({ left: '100%'}))
        ]),
        query(':enter', [
          animate('300ms ease-out', style({ left: '0%'}))
        ])
      ]),
      query(':enter', animateChild()),
    ]),
    transition('* <=> FilterPage', [
      style({ position: 'relative' }),
      query(':enter, :leave', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%'
        })
      ]),
      query(':enter', [
        style({ left: '-100%'})
      ]),
      query(':leave', animateChild()),
      group([
        query(':leave', [
          animate('200ms ease-out', style({ left: '100%'}))
        ]),
        query(':enter', [
          animate('300ms ease-out', style({ left: '0%'}))
        ])
      ]),
      query(':enter', animateChild()),
    ])
  ]);
```

Comment: Did you see any errors in your developer console?

Comment: I don't find any error in console as well as in cmd

Comment: this should work

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still looking, you are passing the wrong parameter to `prepareRoute(outlet)`. Your variable name is `#o`, so you need to pass `prepareRoute(o)`